# excel vba created active x button missing text until moved in design mode

Tags: vba, excel

So I had everything working in my giant excel project until today. I have a very large project of code that I'm running on a multitude of sheets within a large group of workbooks. Part of this code makes buttons as needed. I edited some unrelated range formats to sheets and when I ran my code, one of my 3 button creation processes created buttons that appear to have no Caption. However, when I enter design mode and move those buttons, the text appears (I was trying to look at the properties when I found this out). All of the buttons have valid values for their caption, but none of them are actually being displayed until manually moved and then moved back. Considering there are ~ 10,000 of these buttons between all the workbooks, this is a problematic manual process. (luckily I haven't run the code on all the workbooks yet)

I can't for the life of me figure out why these buttons are having this happen, but it is now a consistent behavior. The other active x buttons are not having the same problem.

Here is the code for an active x button that works:

```
Sub AddNAMEButton(tc As Range, Sht As Worksheet)
    Dim NewButton As OLEObject
    Dim ButtonExist As Boolean
    Dim ButtonName As String
    ButtonExist = False
    ButtonName = Sht.Name & tc.Row & "NAME"
    With Sht
       On Error Resume Next
        ButtonName = Sht.OLEObjects(ButtonName)
        If ButtonName <> "" Then
            ButtonExist = True
        Else
            ButtonExist = False
        End If
        If ButtonExist = True Then
            Sht.OLEObjects(ButtonName).Delete
            GoTo CreateButton
            On Error GoTo 0
        Else
            GoTo CreateButton
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    End With

CreateButton:
    With tc.Cells(1, 6)
                Set NewButton = Sht.OLEObjects.Add _
                    (ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", _
                    Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, _
                    Left:=.Left, _
                    Top:=.Top, _
                    Height:=.Height, _
                    Width:=.Width)
                NewButton.Object.Caption = "NAME"
                NewButton.Object.Font.Size = 9
                NewButton.Object.Font.Bold = True
                NewButton.Name = Sht.Name & .Row & "NAME"
                NewButton.Object.Font.Name = "Arial"
                NewButton.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
    End With
End Sub
```

And here is the code of the problematic button:

```
Sub AddAppButton(tc As Range, Sht As Worksheet)
    Dim NewButton As OLEObject
    Dim ButtonExist As Boolean
    Dim ButtonName As String
    ButtonExist = False
    ButtonName = Sht.Name & tc.Row & "App"
    With Sht
        On Error Resume Next
        ButtonName = Sht.OLEObjects(ButtonName)
        If ButtonName <> "" Then
            ButtonExist = True
        Else
            ButtonExist = False
        End If
        If ButtonExist = True Then
            Sht.OLEObjects(ButtonName).Delete
            GoTo CreateButton
            On Error GoTo 0
        Else
            GoTo CreateButton
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    End With

CreateButton:
        With tc.Cells(1, 8)
                Set NewButton = Sht.OLEObjects.Add _
                    (ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", _
                    Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, _
                    Left:=.Left, _
                    Top:=.Top, _
                    Height:=.Height, _
                    Width:=.Width)
                NewButton.Object.Caption = "App"
                NewButton.Object.Font.Size = 9
                NewButton.Object.Font.Bold = True
                NewButton.Name = Sht.Name & .Row & "App"
                NewButton.Object.Font.Name = "Arial"
                NewButton.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
        End With
End Sub
```

In the code that calls these, they are called right next to each other:

```
Call Module3.AddAppButton(tc, Sht)
Call Module3.AddNAMEButton(tc, Sht)
```

That's part of 6 different button creation calls (2 before them and 2 after) and all of those other 4 active x buttons are working fine. Just the App button is having the problem. I've tried a few things now, changing that buttons default location on the worksheet, editing those button's formatting after the final sheet formatting, etc. Nothing has worked. I cannot for the life of me figure out what would be the difference between the two processes I posted (other than name), and I also can't figure out why the value of the caption is on the button, but is not being displayed on the button until the button is moved on the sheet.

Before anyone recommends not working with active x buttons, I also have other form types and all of the OLEObject types need to be maintained as that type so that when other processes run, they can manipulate all of the like-typed of objects (all OLEObjects are the same context while other form types have other contexts). So it's much more complicated than just "don't work with active x buttons!" as them being active x buttons is serving a specific purpose.

Copying the code I'm posting into a new worksheet results in buttons that are not broken, so I already assume that there's something else really weird going on, but I'm posting this hoping that someone has run into something similar and might be able to help figure out what's breaking in my document display (it really does seem like just a display issue, albeit one which cripples the excel app).

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turns out to not be code related, but is instead an issue when creating a button on a sheet with hidden rows/columns. It may not be a simple as that, but I was able to resolve this just by putting a Sht.Rows.Hidden = False and Sht.Columns.Hidden = False before the CreateButton code. This resolved the issue entirely.

I suspect there is some sort of issue within excel and addressing point offset properties like "top" and "left" when something is being referenced in relation to (after, touching, something) hidden rows/columns. I'd dig into it more to figure out exactly why this happens, but I've got other work to do.